# TBackendPush send Push to Kinvey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, kinvey

I am trying to send a JSON message to kinvey backend, anyway the custom endpoint logic is exiting with error message.

my code is

```
BackendPush1.GCM.Title   := 'title';

BackendPush1.GCM.Message := '{ "message":"hi", "caption":"batman" }';

BackendPush1.Push;
```

When I send it - on the backend I am receiving an "Bad Request" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message in this case shall be a simple string. Not JSON.